# Is there any software that can automatically zoom to certain extent for many images?

Tags: graphs, zoom

I want to run 2 "services" at once. One, is upload non-profit Quran videos on YouTube while highlighting every word the reciter says, word by word (I currently have a [channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJv0STX-xSkapow54orIJ6g) that highlights verse by verse, but I'm changing to word by word). This one shows a zoomed in view of the Mushaf, a Mushaf has 15 lines, but because of zooming, this one only shows a maximum of 5 lines.

Two, is offer a free Quran reading program on the internet or also available for download. The users will in shaa Allah have the option to read it by themselves, or click on a button, choose their reciter, and then the Mushaf will highlight word by word what the reciter utters.

You see, Service One only show a maximum of 5 lines (and every page on the Mushaf has 15 lines, except the first and second page), but Service Two will need to show a total of 15 lines, is there any way I can work on both of them at once? I want to do that by first only coloring the Words on a full page, and then find a software to somehow convert the style of Service Two to the style of Service One.

For example, here's what a word will look like using Service One:
[image: Service One]

And here's how it will look like using Service Two:
[image]
Notice that (in Service One) I had to paint white over the upper parts of some words because these parts were unnecessary and belonged to words that are outside the first five lines, would be wonderful if there's a way to automatically remove those from all the images, because Word by Word would make for many images that would be hard to remove the "upper parts" of unbelonging words from each of these images. Indeed, I count the name of the Surah (that rectangular thing at the top of the page) and Bismillahi Ar-Rahmani Ar-Raheem (below the name of the Surah) each as one line.

As you can see, this is very important so please if you don't know the answer share this post.

Jazakum Allah khayran, any question please ask in the comments.